# Binary search index position

Tags: java

how to get highest and lowest index position in Collections.binarysearch() through key value

```
int curIndex = Collections.binarysearch(myList,"String");
int highIndex = ?
```

Comment: what do you mean by lowIndex? it returns the index of the item in the list if it exists.

Comment: Are you after the index of the first and last occurrence of "String" (assuming there are multiple occurences), or are you after something like `highIndex = lowIndex + "String".length()`?

Answer (score 4):

You're already making an incorrect assumption: that the value returned will be the lowest index. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29):

> If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.

Basically, once you've found *one* match, you just need to walk down the list until you find a non-match to get the lowest index, and walk up the list until you find a non-match to get the highest index.

```
int found = Collections.binarySearch(myList, "String");
int lowIndex = found;
while (lowIndex > 0 && myList.get(lowIndex - 1).equals("String")) {
    lowIndex--;
}
int highIndex = found;
while (highIndex + 1 < myList.size()
       && myList.get(highIndex + 1).equals("String")) {
    highIndex++;
}
```

(You could rewrite those `while` loops as `for` loops with an empty body if you wanted to, but I find this more readable.)